# Sorting Non-identical Merged cell in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, sorting

I have to sort the Excel Sheet's Specific Range which contains non-identical Merged Cells, how can i sort it. The sorting column contains unique entries. Can someone tell me how to sort it, since excel's inbuilt sorting algorithm does not sort non-identical cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer to sort a excel range containing non identical merged cells.
The Name of the range which we have to sort is "SortRangeValue" and we are performing the sorting on column named "column1"  and which is very fist column of the "SortRangeValue" Range. The sorting is done Column to be sorted inthis case "column1" which is the very first column in the range.
Here is the code, it takes some time to execute as no of rows increases, and in my given range i am having one hidden row at last, that's why i am running my code till lastRow-3, here 3 represents 1 for hidden row, 1 for length-1 for bubble sort and 1 for 0 based indexing in excel.(1+1+1=3)

```
Private Sub Ascending_Click()
    Dim myRange As Range        'variable to hold the Named Range
    Dim rowCount As Long        'variable to hold the Number of Rows in myRange
    Dim colCount As Long        'variable to hold the Number of Columns in myRange
    Dim rowStartIndex As Long   'variable to hold the Starting Row index of myRange
    Dim colStartIndex As Long   'variable to hold the Starting Col index of myRange
    Dim iIndex As Long          'Variable used for iteration
    Dim jIndex As Long          'Variable used for iteration
    Dim current As Long         'used in bubble sort to hold the value of the current jIndex item
    Dim currentPlusOne As Long          'used in bubble sort to hold the value of the  jIndex+1 item
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'dont update screen until we sort the range.
    Set myRange = Range("SortRangeValue")   'Get the range
    '
    'get the columns and rows from where the row start, since Range can start from any cell
    ' also the no. of columns and rows in rows
    rowStartIndex = myRange.Row
    colStartIndex = myRange.Column
    colCount = myRange.Columns.Count
    rowCount = myRange.Rows.Count
    Dim tempCal As Long
    tempCal = rowCount + rowStartIndex          ' get the row no of last range
    'here colStartIndex is the very first column which is to be sorted
    For iIndex = 0 To rowCount - 3 Step 1       ' Run a bubble sort loop
        For jIndex = 0 To rowCount - iIndex - 3 Step 1
            rowIndex = jIndex + rowStartIndex
            current = Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex)      ' calculate the rowIndex
            currentPlusOne = Cells(rowIndex + 1, colStartIndex)    ' get current cell value, and next row cell value.
            If current > currentPlusOne Then        'campair the values
                ' if match found, select entire row of the values and shift it them down by copying it to some temp location here it is (3,16)
                'get entire row from firstCol(colStartIndex) to last column (colStartIndex+colCount-1)
                Range(Cells(rowIndex + 1, colStartIndex), Cells(rowIndex + 1, colStartIndex + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(3, 16)
                Range(Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(rowIndex + 1, colStartIndex)
                Range(Cells(3, 16), Cells(3, 16 + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex)
                Range(Cells(3, 16), Cells(3, 16 + colCount - 1)).Value = ""
            End If
           Next jIndex  ' increment jINdex
        Next iIndex     'Increment iIndex
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True       'display result on screen
  End Sub
```